# Yorkie git hooks always fail with "not found"

Tags: husky, git-husky

I am using yorkie 2.0.0, and cannot run any custom shell scripts in my git hooks. My directory structure looks like this:

```
<project root>
|-- .githooks
|   |-- commit-msg
|
|-- package.json
|-- .git
|   |-- hooks
|   |   |-- <all the proper yorkie git hooks files>
|   |
|   |-- <other .git stuff>
|
|-- <lots of other irrelevant files>
```

And my package.json has this gitHooks section:

```
"gitHooks": {
  "commit-msg": ".githooks/commit-msg $GIT_PARAMS"
}
```

The `commit-msg` file is definitely executable, this is the `ls -l` line:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dan dan 400 Sep 14 08:51 commit-msg
```

When I create a commit, I get the following output:

```
 > running commit-msg hook: .githooks/commit-msg $GIT_PARAMS
/bin/sh: 1: .githooks/commit-msg: not found

commit-msg hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

I have tried all kinds of different directory structures and it is never found. I have changed my gitHook script in package.json to things like `ls .githooks` and the file shows up then.

What is going on? Why can't yorkie find my file?

(I've tagged this with husky because yorkie is a fork of husky with fairly minimal changes and there is no yorkie tag. The issue here is probably not specific to yorkie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `not found` was a red herring. This was a line endings issue.

After I converted the line endings inside `commit-msg` to LF, everything worked. I added the following line to my `.gitattributes` so this wouldn't keep happening every time I checked out a branch:

```
.githooks/* text eol=lf
```